# Split a long grep pattern into multiple lines

Tags: grep, split

To make my script a bit more readable I'm trying to split my long grep pattern. Is that possible?

**Example, in by bash script, instead of this long line**

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda | grep -Ei "Spin_Retry_Count|Calibration_Retry_Count|Reallocated_Event_Count|Offline_Uncorrectable|Reallocated_Sector_Ct|Current_Pending_Sector|CRC_Error_Count|Multi_Zone_Error_Rate|Temperature|CRC_Error_Count|Runtime_Bad_Block|Erase_Fail_Count|Program_Fail_C|End-to-End_Error" | awk '{print $2" "$10}')
```

I want to split into something like that, to make things more readable

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda | grep -Ei "Spin_Retry_Count|"\
                                   "Calibration_Retry_Count|"\
                                   "Reallocated_Event_Count|"\
                                   "Offline_Uncorrectable|"\
                                   "Reallocated_Sector_Ct|"\
                                   "Current_Pending_Sector|"\
                                   "CRC_Error_Count|"\
                                   "Multi_Zone_Error_Rate|"\
                                   "Temperature|"\
                                   "CRC_Error_Count|"\
                                   "Runtime_Bad_Block|"\
                                   "Erase_Fail_Count|"\
                                   "Program_Fail_C|"\
                                   "End-to-End_Error" | awk '{print $2" "$10}')
```

Comment: could you provide more details? what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence "backslash-newline-whitespace" is replaced by a single space, so you are adding spaces into the pattern.

Using bash arrays can lead to readable code, something like this:

```
words=(
    "Spin_Retry_Count"
    "Calibration_Retry_Count"
    "Reallocated_Event_Count"
    "Offline_Uncorrectable"
    "Reallocated_Sector_Ct"
    "Current_Pending_Sector"
    "CRC_Error_Count"
    "Multi_Zone_Error_Rate"
    "Temperature"
    "CRC_Error_Count"
    "Runtime_Bad_Block"
    "Erase_Fail_Count"
    "Program_Fail_C"
    "End-to-End_Error"
)
# join the words with pipes
pattern=$( IFS='|'; echo "${words[*]}" )

smartctl -a /dev/sda | grep -Ei "$pattern" | awk '{print $2, $10}'
```

We *can* remove grep from the pipeline because GNU awk can do what grep does, but perhaps a little wordier:

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda | gawk -v p="$pattern" -v IGNORECASE=1 '$0 ~ p {print $2, $10}'
```